# send data from php array in javascript forEach loop to url of ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to loop through the results of a mysql query in php, the output of the query is an array similar to [10201,10202]. I want to take the results and loop it to the variable named id in my javascript function and loop it through the url of my ajax call. The goal is to take the id and use it in a sql query on another page to change the date of the id in our database.

mysql query:

```
<?php
        // sql query for # print all open orders function
        $sql = "SELECT Order_PID
                FROM `Order`
                WHERE SHIPDATE IS NULL
                AND Address1 IS NOT NULL;";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
                $order[] = $row['Order_PID'];
        }
?>
```

javascript function:
I'm trying to use a forEach function to iterate through the results of the array.

```
$('button#printOpenOrders').on('click', function(e) {
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to print all open orders and mark them as pending?")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // prints all open orders
        window.open("/resources/scripts/allOpenPDF.php");
        var arr = $order;
        arr.forEach(function(id) { // <====this function
            $.ajax({
            url: "/resources/scripts/pending-order.php?id=" + id, // <===this variable
            datatype : "string",
            success : function(data) {
                location.reload(true);
                }
            })
        })
     }
});
```

and if it helps here is my callback script

```
<?php 

    // login validation
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] != true) {
        $url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/index.php';
        header("Location: ../../index.php");
    }
    // establish connection to database
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources/scripts/dbconnect.php';
    $conn = openConnection();

    // capture id 
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $pendingDate = date_create_from_format("m/d/Y", "07/26/1996");
    $pendingDate = date_format($pendingDate, "Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE       `Order`
                           SET          SHIPDATE = ?
                           WHERE        Order_PID = ?");
    $sql->bind_param("si", $pendingDate, $id);
    $sql->execute();

    echo "success";

    closeConnection($conn);

?>
```

If parts of my code don't make sense, I'm new to this and I am using my currently limited knowledge to frankenstein all of this together. Any nudges in the right direction would be super helpful.

Comment: Why are you sending the IDs to another page to do the update? Why not do it straight away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can output $order variable contents, but you need to use PHP and also you must encode it using json format, so this could actually work:

```
var arr = <?PHP echo json_encode($order); ?>;
```

But it is error-prone, the syntax is not really nice to read, and if that variable somehow becomes in the format you are not expecting it could lead to another JavaScript syntax error.

But the best way in my opinion would be to make an AJAX request and get those order IDS, and after that you could create another AJAX request that would send all those Order IDS,
so you wouldn't need .forEach stuff and your logic of handling multiple orders need to be modified in order to accommodate for these changes.

But since you already have those IDS in PHP I mean stored in $order variable, you could just encode it and send it all the ids at once in a single request.

Comment: This worked and was a big help, thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help, but still later I would really suggest you simplify the logic in JavaScript, so you only send all the IDS in a single request, and then in PHP code you just loop through each id and handle it the way you need it. If you won't have a lot of ids then the benefits are negligible, by passing all the ids in one request you can ensure that each order will be dealt with in order in which they appear, and in your case because for each order you create a new request there is no guarantee that they will be handled in the same order, just to let you know.